# why can not I use PreparedStatement.setObject for DATE?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, jboss6.x, ojdbc

In a very large Java application, according to Oracle advise for date ([Oracle JDBC Reference Information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm)) I try to replace :

```
prepareStatement.setTimestamp(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
```

by :

```
prepareStatement.setObject(1, new oracle.sql.DATE(var14, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())));
```

But i'm getting a SQLException "Invalid column type".

Why ?

I tried to execute the same code in a simplest and it's working !

My hypothesis is that somewhere in the application a piece of code prevents me from using this code.

What kind of code can do this ?

Query :

```
select * from SOMETABLE where WFSTATE IN (100, 300) OR WFTIMEOUTTIME < ?
```

DDL for SOMETABLE :

```
CREATE TABLE "DB"."SOMETABLE" 
(   "ASSIGNEEID" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"MISSIONREPKEY" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"PROCESS_CASEFOLDERID" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
"S_DISPATCH" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
"S_EVENTSEQUENCE" NUMBER(10,0), 
"S_EVENTTIME" DATE, 
"S_GOALCATEGORY" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
"S_WORKSTART" DATE, 
"S_WORKTIME" NUMBER(10,0),
"WFCALLERRTID" NUMBER(18,0), 
"WFCALLERWFID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"WFFLOWENTRYTIME" DATE, 
"WFFLOWEXITTIME" DATE, 
"WFLOCKTIME" DATE, 
"WFLOCKTYPE" NUMBER(10,0), 
"WFLOCKUSER" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"WFPARENTID" NUMBER(18,0), 
"WFPRIORSTEPNAME" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"WFRANDOM" NUMBER(10,0), 
"WFROUTINGTICKETID" NUMBER(18,0), 
"WFSTATE" NUMBER(10,0), 
"WFSTEPENTRYTIME" DATE, 
"WFTIMEOUTTIME" DATE, 
"WFWORKITEMID" NUMBER(18,0), 
"WFWORKSTEPNAME" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"WORKFLOWID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"WORKFLOWVERSION" NUMBER(10,0)
) (...);
```

Oracle DataBase version : Oracle XE 11.2.0-1

OJdbc version : ojdbc6 11.2.0.3

Server : JBoss AS 6 with a dataSource :

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/Sonora</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <user-name>sonora</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>50</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    <connection-property name="oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion">false</connection-property>
    <new-connection-sql>alter session set nls_comp='ansi' nls_sort='GENERIC_BASELETTER' nls_language='FRENCH'</new-connection-sql>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

Comment: Can you post your SQL statement ? And table schema ?

Comment: What is the Java type `DATE` that you are using? It's apparently something else than `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`. The JDBC driver doesn't understand any arbitrary type that you pass to it.

Comment: @Jesper i'm using oracle.sql.DATE

Comment: @Gaël Thanks, it's done.

Comment: Are you sure that your version of OJDBC supports `oracle.sql.DATE` ?

Comment: @Gaël I hope ! The class oracle.sql.DATE comes from my OJdbc driver.

Comment: It is entirely possible that the Oracle JDBC driver only supports the `setObject` conversions required by the JDBC specification. You might want to check their documentation if it has any information about that.